# How to have a variable accessing through different class methods in PHP?

Tags: php

How is it possible to have a variable inside a class in PHP that is accessible through different methods of the same class?
What's the location and syntax of declaration, initialization and accessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example.

```
<?php
class HelloWorld {
 var $message = '';

 function __construct() {
   $this->message = 'Hello World';
 }

 function say_hi() {
   echo $this->message;
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read "Classes and Objects: The Basics" in the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 2):

You can access every variable from your class in all the methods with this :

```
$this->myVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

a variable can be declared inside the class.

```
<?php
class ExampleClass {
public $pub; // accessable anywhere
protected $pro; // can only be called by this class and classes that extend this class (inherit)
private $pri; // only accessed by this class

}?>
```

Variable scope is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)